# npx create-react-app command error (babel/generator)

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, create-react-app, npx

When I run npx create-react-app command error it gives the following error

`Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/generator@^7.21.4.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\baris.karapelit\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-27T12_47_03_649Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json`

npm install
npm init -y
npm install react react-dom react-scripts cra-template
npm install @babel/generator@7.21.3

I tried all the above commands but the same error persists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIam8.png)